# How to automate find and replace link in Google Sheets from form photo submission

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

Trying to automate find and replace function on form submission within sheets.
Principal/Teacher submits a photo through a Google Form and I want to change from the file link to a search to link within the Google Sheet. Currently have to manually do this and would like to automate the process.

Here are the find and replace codes currently using find

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=
```

and replacing with

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=
```

Comment: Welcome. 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a formula with the [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215) function

```
=SUBSTITUTE(D8,"https://drive.google.com/open?id=", 
               "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=")
```

[image]

Comment: That would work, I am just wanting to have it automatically change when a form is submitted.  Is this even possible?